# Environment variable with complicated symbols

Tags: php, symfony, environment-variables, yaml

In parameters I have

```
some.pass: '%env(resolve:some_pass)%'
```

.env

```
some_pass=#v[b'<:)TY:-U8T>p[z&.4G@)uB$~z1N
```

And when I call

`$container->getParameter('some.pass')`

I just get an empty string or an error with another type of pass.

My guess is that it's beacause of symbols in password.

How can I escape string in .env file or so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Problem is with your first character `#` that is used for comments in `.env` files.

So when you setup in `.env` file

```
parameter=#123
```

that will be resolved like empty string `""` cause first character is `#` and everything after `#` will be consider as comment.

Way to put `#` in your parameter is to surround parameter value with double quotes.

`parameter="#123"` will be resolved to string `#123`.

Additional if you also want to add `"` in parameter you can with escaping character using `\`.
`parameter="#12\"3"` will be resolved to string `#12"3`